# (Scala) How to create large hardcoded collections (~2000 objects)

Tags: scala, jvm

I have some data which I'd like to model using two immutable.Maps with each having ~50 vectors and each of those vectors having ~20 objects (each of them holds a few integers and a few short strings), totaling ~2000 objects.

I won't be adding or deleting anything from those data, but I'll be querying those a lot with maps and filters (I'm writing a play server). Since there is no worry for data integrity from bad writes, and seeing the data set is not that big, I figured I would just use scala collections instead of some external database.

I took the most straightforward path: I just wrote two huge hard-coded Maps in a source file. The size of the file (only containing the object with two Maps) was about 350k. Ensime didn't warn me of any errors, so it wasn't until I ran `sbt compile` when I got the error message `Could not write class mypackage/myBigListOfStuffs$ because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method scala/package$'s code too large!`

What would be the quickest way to workaround this limitation?
Startup time doesn't matter since this is going to be a server, and I would like the method to be without too much hassle.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the data into a separate JSON file, and then deserialize it using [Jackson module for Scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val obj = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](jsonString)
```